# nhibernate join table value function

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm discovering nhibernate right now. Thus my question is maybe very stupid :)

What I'm trying to do (I'm working with a legacy database) is to get an entity which some of its data are coming from a table value function.
My entity is the following

```
public class Entity
{
  public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
  ....
  public virtual int AccessRightId { get; set; }
}
```

where AccessRightId comes from the table value function (fp_AccessRight('userId'))

I have the following mapping

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
  {
    public EntityMap ()
    {
      this.Id(entity => entity .Id);          
      this.Join(
          "fp_AccessRight('userId')",
            join =>
            {
                join.Fetch.Join();
                join.KeyColumn("EntityId");
                join.Map(t => t.AccessRightId, "AccessRightType");
                join.Table();
            });
    }        
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to substitute 'userId' by any value.
Thanks.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you could post it as answer and accept it so others find it more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it.

The trick was to make the join like this :

```
this.Join("fp_ACCOUNT_ACL(:AclFilter.userId)"
```

and then simpley to enable the filter

```
this.session.EnableFilter("AclFilter").SetParameter("userId", "bdd#5");
```

I found an example [here](http://ayende.com/blog/1954/localizing-nhibernate-contextual-parameters).